# ModuleNotFoundError while creating minimal python package

Tags: python, import, package, relative-path, pypi

I made a very simple python package by following [the packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/):

```
tester
├── A.py
├── B.py
└── __init__.py
```

The contents of `A.py` are simply:

```py
import B
```

`__init__.py` and `B.py` are empty files.

I uploaded the package to [testpypi](https://test.pypi.org/project/example-pkg-2-cuppajoeman/) and installed it in a virtual environment. I started first by checking if it works by making a simple `test.py` file:

```py
from tester import A
```

Then I try to run that file:

```sh
(scratch-venv) [ccn@sy337b4 scratch-box]$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ccn/scratch-box/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tester import A
  File "/home/ccn/scratch-box/scratch-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tester/A.py", line 1, in <module>
    import B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

I'm confused because when I was developing the package running `python A.py` never caused an error, but now when I'm importing `A` it doesn't work any more.

(within the venv, aka: client using package) I was able to fix this by changing the contents of `A.py` to :

```py
from tester import B
```

But that's not a solution because when I go back to developing the package I get this error when running `python A.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ccn/tester_package/src/tester/A.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tester import B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tester'
```

---

Finally for full context I will post the structure of the package. I am developing in src/tester

```
.
├── build
│   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
│   └── lib
│       └── tester
│           ├── A.py
│           ├── B.py
│           └── __init__.py
├── dist
│   ├── example_pkg_2_cuppajoeman-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── example-pkg-2-cuppajoeman-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── example_pkg_2_cuppajoeman.egg-info
    │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   └── top_level.txt
    └── tester
        ├── A.py
        ├── B.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __pycache__
            └── B.cpython-39.pyc

9 directories, 17 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, in `tester/a.py` you should have either one of those:

```
from . import B
```

```
from tester import B
```

```
import tester.B
```

Comment: Hi there `from . import B` solves the issue, additionally this page sums it up well: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision